# spring boot + secure jmx

Tags: jmx, spring-boot

By default spring boot exposes a number of JMX endpoints, has anyone had any experience securing these, it seems there is no security surrounding JMX.

The only config available to Spring boot:

```
endpoints.jmx.enabled=true
endpoints.jmx.domain= # the JMX domain, defaults to 'org.springboot'
endpoints.jmx.unique-names=false
endpoints.jmx.enabled=true
endpoints.jmx.staticNames=
```

I have seen examples using JmxSecurityAuthenticator, should I follow this pattern.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK securing the JMX connections is all about how you set up the server. I think you just need to add a `@Bean` of type `ConnectorServerFactoryBean`.